# How to permanently remap petadactyl keys

Tags: firefox, vim, firefox-extensions, pentadactyl

Using pentadactyl extension for firefox, how can I persistently change a key mapping. For example, how could I change shift+j to go to the next tab next time I open the browser? The command map J gt works as expected but reverts to the default upon closing the browser window. How do I cause the software to remember the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: `touch .pentadactylrc` in the home folder does it.